# Software to find similar music samples

Tags: music, music-production

I'm looking for program that can help me find music samples within a library which are "similar" to an input sample. By sample I mean a short (1-10 seconds) audio file, typically in .wav or .aif format. The meaning of similar in this context means that two samples sound tonally and texturally similar.

For example, let's say I'm looking for a very particular "drum snare" sound, and I have a library of 1,000 snare sounds. I know that 2 or 3 of them are close to what I'm looking for but not quite there. I'd like a tool that can find all the "similar" snare sounds within the library given the 2 or 3 that I found manually.

The type of software, (ie: command line, UI, web) doesn't matter that much, as long as it ideally works on Mac OS. It should have the following features:

1. Should accept an example audio file of format .wav or .aif as input and search my sample library for a list of "similar" sounds. The exact number of results is not important as long as it can do its best to find the most similar sounds.
2. Ideally it should work from the command line OR as a standalone program so I can point it to my local filesystem where I store my sample files.

Answer (score 1):

[Acoustid](https://acoustid.org) has a list of specific [applications](https://acoustid.org/applications) including [Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/) which rely on open source technology but for any serious use I would suggest taking a look at [ARCloud](https://www.acrcloud.com/music-recognition) for [music recognition](https://www.acrcloud.com/docs/acrcloud/tutorials/identify-music-by-sound/).